# Convergence rate of an iterative scheme

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

Given an iteration scheme of the form : $x_{k+1}=x_k+t_kd_k$. It is also known that there are $\delta,C>0,D\geq 0$ such that if $x_k \in B_{\delta}(x_*)$ holds we have the following estimate:

$ ||x_{k+1}-x_*||\leq C(||x_k-x_*||+D)||x_k-x_*||$.

What is the convergence rate of the iteration scheme if $C=D$ ?

I've tried to plug in $C=D$ inside this expression and tried to expand and see what the RHS looks like. I thought I might be able to factor out some term to make it look nice but was unable to do so. Any suggestions as to how to determine the rate of convergence of this scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d_k = ||x_k-x_*||$.
We are given
$d_{k+1} \le C d_k(D+d_k)
=
CD d_k + C d_k^2
$.

This becomes

$\begin{align}
d_{k+1} 
&\le C d_k(d_k+D) \\
&\le CD d_k+C d_k^2\\
&\le C D(CD d_{k-1}+C d_{k-1}^2)+C (CD d_{k-1}+C d_{k-1}^2)^2\\
&= C^2D^2 d_{k-1}+C^2 D d_{k-1}^2+C^3d_{k-1}^2 ( D+ d_{k-1})^2\\
&= C^2 D^2d_{k-1}+C^2 Dd_{k-1}^2+C^3d_{k-1}^2 ( D^2+ 2D d_{k-1}+d_{k-1}^2)\\
&= C^2 D^2d_{k-1}+C^2 Dd_{k-1}^2+C^3D^2d_{k-1}^2 + 2C^3D d_{k-1}^3+C^3d_{k-1}^4\\
&= C^2 D^2d_{k-1}+C^2D(1+CD) d_{k-1}^2+2C^3Dd_{k-1}^3+C^3d_{k-1}^4\\
\end{align}
$

If $D=C$,
this becomes
$d_{k+1}
\le C^4d_{k-1}+C^3(1+C^2) d_{k-1}^2+2C^4d_{k-1}^3+C^3d_{k-1}^4
$.

It looks like
$d_{k+1} = C^{m+1}D^{m+1}d_{k-m} + O(d_{k-m}^2)$
for integer $m \ge 0$.

Looking at this,
there doesn't seem to me 
to be any obvious reason
why $D=C$ would be special.
$D=0$ would certainly be.